# HTML/CSSmenu at the bottom is clashing with the images in the center

Tags: html, css

I am new to html,css and am currently working on a page. 
I am unable to align the menu at the right bottom side.It is clashing with my 3 pictures in the middle. Also logo at the bottom left keeps changing when ever I make changes to the images at the centre. Kindly go through the code and let me know.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.background{
 position: relative;
}
.background .text {
 position: absolute;
 top: 300px;
 left: 300px;
 width: 300px;
}
.logo {
 position:absolute;
 left: 10px;
 bottom: 10px;
}
#bottomnav ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 right:0px;
 bottom:0px;
}
#bottomnav ul li {
 width: 0%;
 float: right ;
 text-align:right;
}
.images{
 width:250;
 height:250;
 display:inline;
 float:right;
 border:2px solid #FFF;
 margin-top:300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="background">
 <img src="images/landing_page.png"/>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>welcome</h1>
    <p>office</p>
    <p>ink</p>
  </div>
  <div class="logo"> <img src="images/logo_03.png"/> </div>
  <div class="images">
  <img src="images/top1.jpg" width="400" style="float:right"/>
  <img src="images/top2.jpg"width="400" style="float:right"/>
  <img src="images/top3.jpg" width="400" style="float:right"/>
  </div>
  <div id="bottomnav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot load images, check out url's so we can handle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Divi,
check out clearfix.

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

You will need to apply the fix to the image parent container (.images).

Also you are using a lot of absolute positing, when it is not necessarily needed.

You could float the logo left and image container right, while applying an explicit width to each.

Also why do you have .images set to 250 width, and images are 400 width?

Comment: That doesn't mean anything, question is partially unclear. Divi give us a fiddle so we can see where is the problem.

Comment: What doesn't mean anything. 'That' is ambiguous. Please clarify your comment, so I can help you understand my answer.

Comment: He's question is almost unclear, we need a fiddle so we can solve the issue. And width of images is unimportant.

Comment: @Milan actually, OP question is clear enough to understand.  OP provided code and its not specific to a certain environment so a fiddle isnt needed in the question, though it would be helpful.  However ARWVISIONS,your answer is full of only observations and suggestions rather than solutions.  The content of this answer should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Yes, fiddle would be very helpful, that's what im talking about.

Comment: Pretty new to the site, so thanks for the advice.  I'll keep that in mind :) Until today I was unable to make comments.  Not sure what changed.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this is the answer you're looking for, but this solution solves the problem you were having regarding the menu not showing up on the bottom right hand side (I think is what you were trying to achieve with some of your css):  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/72/

I reorganized the structure of your html a little bit because you said the logo should be at the bottom (I'm assuming below the other larger pictures).

```
<div class="background">
    <img src="images/landing_page.png"/>
    <div class="text">
        <h1>welcome</h1>
        <p>office</p>
        <p>ink</p>
    </div>        
    <div class="images">
        <img src="images/top1.jpg" width="400" style="display:inline-block;"/>
        <img src="images/top2.jpg"width="400" style="display:inline-block;"/>
        <img src="images/top3.jpg" width="400" style="display:inline-block;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="logo"> <img src="images/logo_03.png"/> </div>
    <div id="bottomnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

heres the css:

```
#bottomnav {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}
#bottomnav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#bottomnav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Useful tip: when dealing with css, less is more, try to be concise in your styles so that you dont have to write over styles with other styles and force your way around the DOM.

hope this helps/gets you pointed in the right direction.